# Trouble to install package in Python using Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, installation, pip, package

I hope someone could handle my problem. I want to install the package TTLocVis but unfortunately it does not work. I run the code `pip install TTLocVis` but then I get the error massage:
(This is not the whole traceback because this would be too long. But the same error messages appear for pandas and wordcloud

```
Building wheel for numpy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/User /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/q2/124555ys0438cph2m_5jcj4c0000gn/T/pip-install-yencgdzt/numpy_52d5fc8b055c49e4a1a2a84ff0a2457d/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/q2/124555ys0438cph2m_5jcj4c0000gn/T/pip-install-yencgdzt/numpy_52d5fc8b055c49e4a1a2a84ff0a2457d/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/q2/124555ys0438cph2m_5jcj4c0000gn/T/pip-wheel-_y075drp
       cwd: /private/var/folders/q2/124555ys0438cph2m_5jcj4c0000gn/T/pip-install-yencgdzt/numpy_52d5fc8b055c49e4a1a2a84ff0a2457d/
  Complete output (120 lines):
  Running from numpy source directory.
  /private/var/folders/q2/124555ys0438cph2m_5jcj4c0000gn/T/pip-install-yencgdzt/numpy_52d5fc8b055c49e4a1a2a84ff0a2457d/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:476: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
    return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)
  blas_opt_info:
  blas_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
FOUND:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
      library_dirs = ['/Users/User/opt/anaconda3/lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/Users/User/opt/anaconda3/include']
  
    FOUND:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
      library_dirs = ['/Users/User/opt/anaconda3/lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/Users/User/opt/anaconda3/include']
  
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
  lapack_opt_info:
  lapack_mkl_info:
  customize UnixCCompiler
    FOUND:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
      library_dirs = ['/Users/User/opt/anaconda3/lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/Users/User/opt/anaconda3/include']
  
    FOUND:
      libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
      library_dirs = ['/Users/User/opt/anaconda3/lib']
      define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
      include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', '/Users/User/opt/anaconda3/include']
```

Comment: The installation fails when trying to install numpy. Can you try to install numpy first. 
```pip install numpy```

Comment: numpy is already installed.

Comment: Thats quite weird, because pip wouldn´t try to install numpy then. TTLocVIs needs version 1.16.1 of numpy. Is this version installed?

Comment: My numpy version is 1.19.2. So after your command I tryred to install version 1.16.1 but then I got the same error message as before  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after reading your comments I propose the following temporary solution to possibly solve your problem.

You have to clone the repository. Then open setup.py in the created directory and remove the following part "==1.16.1" in line 17.

```
git clone https://github.com/xillig/TTLocVis.git
```

- Remove the part "==1.16.1" in line 17 of setup.py

```
cd TTLocVis
pip install .
```

Edit: I don´t know why the authors of TTLocVis need exactly this one numpy version. Perhaps it works with your version too.

Comment: When I try this way I must also change the versions of pandas and wordcloud in the TTLocVis setup but unfortunately when I try to install wordcloud the same error appears again  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Comment: Ok. Can you please give me the whole traceback? I suppose that there are additional informations after "customize UnixCCompiler".

Comment: Ok thank you. I have to spilt the whole traceback in multiple comments because it is too long

Comment: @Pferfferhausen Can´t you edit your initial post and paste it into the code snippet? :)

Comment: Both does not work because the whole traceback is 44 sites long :(  When I want only to post the part about numpy, stackoverflow says it is to many code

Comment: I have now edited the initial post with as much traceback code as possible. Hope that this will be helpful

Comment: @Pferfferhausen You are using Mac OS, right? Can you please try the command ```xcode-select --install``` first. Then try to install the package again :)

Comment: Yes I using MacOs. Did I need to install another package for this code or is xcode a filler? Because I get the error: name 'xcode' is not defined

Comment: Have you copied the command? Did you have a whitespace between "xcode" and "-select"? It must be ```xcode-select --install```.
Xcode include command line tools and c compiler that you need to compile numy.

Comment: Yes I copied the code. But still I get xcode is not defined